# What does "?-" mean in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

What does `?-` mean in Prolog?

for example:

```
?- consult(solve)
```

Comment: You can check the link [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Rules_and_facts) Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?-` is typically the prompt of the top level loop or top level shell — which is the place where you can ask queries and enter commands. It has similar functionality as the read-eval-print loop in other languages.

In some systems this prompt is or used to be `| ?-` which is the more traditional prompt.  This prompt comes from one of the earlier Prolog systems of ~1978, DECsystem 10 Prolog. The OS prompt for input was `|` and the user had to type `?- X is 1+1.` to enter a query.

Answer (score 2):

Within a prolog interpreter you can request data (that's basically running prolog scripts), the system replies with a yes or no. The interpreter signals with `?-`, that he awaits a request.

Example:

```
?- male(adam).
yes.
?- male(eve).
no.
```

Read more in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) for it

Comment: I see this in a script. I want to know why programmer has written `?-` before the command. why doesn't he write `consult(solve)` without "?-" ?

Comment: My first thought would be he wants to demonstrate the execution of his script. Without seeing it though hard to guess.